# How can I access existing core data from a Xcode App that is being rewritten in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, core-data, xamarin.forms

We created an iOS app completely native in xcode Objective-C and used core-data to store some data. We needed the app to be cross platfrom so we completely rewrote the app in Xamarin Forms to get it for iOS, Android, and UWP. The xamarin version uses SQLite to store the data so this works fine with Android and UWP as they didn't exist before.

I want to be able to release an update for the iOS version which will bring the code from native to Xamarin. I would like to on start up, detect if there is data saved in core data and loop through and store it in the SQLite database. I'm not sure how to go about checking if the device already has core data.

In the native Xcode, we created a model that was a GUI to set everything up and then the core data classes just existed and we were able to save to it. Since that class isn't the same as what Xamarin as I'm not sure what to do.

So the main question is how can I access existing core data stores in Xamarin forms? After this, I can loop through the records and convert them to SQLite's version myself.

Comment: you can use the CoreData APIs in your Xamarin iOS project

Comment: @Jason How would that work with existing models that were created with the visual designer that wouldn't exist in the Xamarin iOS project? That I feel is the main "trick" as I know I can access the API but don't know how to access my classes and data. In my case the class is "History".

Comment: I don't know much detail about core data, but I do know that should be possible

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 You would need to "re-"model those CoreData classes as NSManagedObject based ones to match the entities (assuming they are modeled via Xcode Data Model editor)... Depending upon the complexity of the original models, things can become quite tricky and since Xamarin.iOS does not support ObjC/Swift `@dynamic` properties natively you might have to dive into doing it yourself, as I have for some CoreAnimation/CoreData projects (  https://gist.github.com/sushihangover/327ba6282b2d41d8e10001b7e461bb21)

Comment: BUT I would highly recommend using ObjC to load any existing CoreData and dump it via Json back to C#. Create an ObjC static library or framework using your existing Xcode Model(s) and intagrate that into your Xamarin.iOS project via a binding project.

Comment: @SushiHangover Do you have any examples or know of any tutorial/articles that would help with your JSON idea? That sounds like a good path to go down as I can easily parse the json with json.net on the C# side and then put it in the SQLite database. I have never made static libraries or binding projects.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 No "single" tutorial/articles off the top of my head, but there are thousands of blog/articles posts of Xcode/ObjC regarding ObjC static lib projects,  CoreData, Json usage in ObjC, etc... once you get a Xcode-based project (main app and your CoreData static library working), then you can move on to the Xamarin side fairly easily: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough

Comment: @SushiHangover Ok so it sounds like, create an objective-C library that works with my xcode project that contains my core data classes. This library will then use core data to get the History classes and then turn it into Json and pass it back to the caller. In order to use it in xamarin, I create a binding project to that library and then I can call it in Xamarin.IOS to get the data to transfer over.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 That is exactly how I would do it 

Comment: I faced this same issue when converting a native iOS app to Xamarin.  CoreData used an underlying SQLite database on iOS (NSSQLiteStoreType).  I was unable to load the data using the core data models in C#, but found the SQLite database in the Documents folder (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal).  Oddly, all tables and fields were prefixed with a "Z" but I was able to read them using the same SQLiteAsyncConnection used for reading the existing Android SQLite database.